# Marcinkiewicz-Zygmund type inequality

Tags: martingales

if we consider an independent sequence of random variables $X_1,X_2,...$ and denote with $S_n = \sum_{j=1}^n X_j$ the sequence of partial sums, one can easily verify the Marcinkiewicz-Zygmund inequality:

$\Vert S_n \Vert_2^2 \leq \sum_{j=1}^n \Vert X_j \Vert_2^2$.

I need such a result where $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of martingales differences or in other words, where $S_n$ is a sequence of martingales. But somehow I manage to find only results of the type

$\Vert S_n \Vert_p^2 \leq c_p \sum_{j=1}^n \Vert X_j \Vert_p^2$

for either $p>2$ or $1<p<2$. Is the case for $p=2$ that trivial?

Comment: For $p=2$,
$$
\mathsf{E}S_n^2=\sum_{j=1}^n \mathsf{E}X_j^2.
$$

Comment: But does such a result also hold true if $X_n$ is not an independent sequence of random variables?

Comment: It suffices to assume that $X_j$'s are uncorrelated (and $\mathsf{E}X_j=0$, $j=1,\ldots,n$).

Comment: And if I can only assume, that $S_n$ is a sequence of martingales? Without any further correlation assumptions

Comment: Well, an MDS satisfies that condition trivially (i.e., the increments of a martingale are uncorrelated).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wasn't aware of this fact. (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1257086/uncorrelated-successive-differences-of-martingale)

Comment: [In general](https://books.google.nl/books?id=NdFGEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA333&dq=Bahr+Esseen+inequality+martingale&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwipiq2Nmez2AhVXt6QKHe7bACEQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=Bahr%20Esseen%20inequality%20martingale&f=false), for an $L^p$-bounded MDS with $1\le p\le 2$,
$$
\mathsf{E}|S_n|^p\le 2\sum_{j=1}^n \mathsf{E}|X_j|^p.
$$